# Make a link for a folder located inside windows 8.1 disk (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: partitioning, windows-8, directory, shortcuts

I want to make a link on my desktop for a folder located in windows 8.1 disk ,every time I

make a link to that folder it just doesn't work after a reboot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Yes it won't work because your windows partition is not mounted by default. To make the shortcut not to disappear after reboot, you have to  add an entry for that Windows partition on `/etc/fstab`. Now the symbolic link will appear on the Desktop even after a reboot.
- See [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) page for creating  fstab entry for your Windows partition.